# Swift 3 try to default value

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift and I'm testing the following code

```
var value: String;
do {
  value = try getValue()
} catch {
  value = "Default Value"
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
let value = (try? getValue()) ?? "Default Value"
```

It works but I feel I may be missing a more obvious solution.

Comment: I don't think there is another simpler solution . You could use `if let value = try? getValue() {` but that's just another variant of your first version.

Comment: What's the _question_?

Comment: @matt Is there a better way? I'm trying to do things the Swift way rather than conflate my Javascript (Node) knowledge onto the Swift language.

Comment: Mmmmm. But what does "better" mean? We're in opinion territory now. It's not as meaningless as "more obvious" but it's close.

Comment: @matt You're right. But I don't want to go down the wrong road as a Swift novice thinking I can't do things differently. The whole ```try?``` is pretty novel (and awesome) coming from Node

Comment: The second solution is shorter, but throwing functions provide error information. Only the first method can give it to you.

Comment: @Wainage That's why in my answer, below, I explained how the `try?` works, just to make sure you're grasping what you're doing (and so that you see that it is right).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is just great, and extremely elegant.

I presume we would like to avoid saying `var` in the first line and initializing the variable later. In *general*, the way to initialize a value immediately with a complex initializer is to use a define-and-call construct:

```
let value: String = {
    do {
        return try getValue()
    } catch {
        return "Default Value"
    }
}()
```

And you would probably want to do that if the `catch` block was returning `error` information that you wanted to capture.

However, in *this* case, where you are disregarding the nature of the error, your expression is much more compact, and does precisely what you want done. `try?` will return an Optional, which will either be unwrapped if we succeed, or, if we fail, will return `nil` and cause the alternate value (`"Default Value"`) to be used.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that is essentially a immediately invoked lambda? That is pretty slick especially if you need to deal with different errors.

Comment: "that is essentially a immediately invoked lambda" You bet your LISP. More discussion from me, here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#SECdefineandcall And here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_computed_initializer

Comment: Thanks for that link and making this info available to the community. I will definitely be perusing it.